# XSLT; Group 2 or more different elements BUT only when adjacent

Tags: xslt, grouping, xslt-2.0

Initially this seemed a trivial problem, but it seems to be harder than I thought.

In the following xml, I want to group adjacent 'note' and p elements only.  A note should always start a notegroup and any following p should be included. No other elements are allowed in the group.

From this:

```
<doc>
 <note />
 <p/>
 <p/>
 <other/>
 <p/>
 <p/>
</doc>
```

To this:

```
<doc>
 <notegroup>
   <note />
   <p/>
   <p/>
 </notegroup>
 <other/>
 <p/>
 <p/>
</doc>
```

Seems ridiculously easy, but the rule is: 'note' and any following 'p'.  Any p on their own are to be ignored (as in the last 2 p above)

With xslt 2.0, if I try something like:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::note) or boolean(self::p)">
```

fails because it also groups the two later p elements.

Or the 'starts-with' approach on the 'note' which seems to indiscriminately group any element after (instead of just the p elements).

The other approach I'm considering is to simply add an attribute to each note and the p that immediately follow the note, and using that to group later, but how can I do that?

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this by being a bit creative with `group-starting-with`, essentially you want to start a new group whenever you see an element that is *not* one that belongs in a `notegroup`.  In your example this would generate two groups - note+p+p and other+p+p, the trick is to only wrap a `notegroup` around groups where the initial item is a `note`, and to simply output groups that are *not* headed by a `note` unchanged

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[not(self::p)]">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::note">
      <notegroup>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </notegroup>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This will wrap all note elements in a `notegroup` even if they don't actually have any following `p` elements. If you don't want to wrap a "bare" note then make it `<xsl:when test="self::note and current-group()[2]">` to trigger the wrapping only when the current group has more than one member.

If you have more than one element name that can be part of a notegroup then you could either list them all in the predicate

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="*[not(self::p|self::ul)]">
```

or declare a variable holding the node names that can be part of a notegroup:

```
<xsl:variable name="notegroupMembers" select="(xs:QName('p'), xs:QName('ul'))" />
```

and then say

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*"
    group-starting-with="*[not(node-name(.) = $notegroupMembers)]">
```

taking advantage of the fact that an `=` comparison where one side is a sequence succeeds if *any* of the items in the sequence match.

Comment: Works! But what an xpath! The problem is I used a simple example of 2 adjacent elements, if I wanted to allow a ul too, the xpath would become a monster.  There must be a simpler way to achieve this? Thanks for the ideas though Ian and great explanation (I have insufficient points to upvote on here but it deserves)

Comment: @user3051624 I've just realised I was overcomplicating matters - it doesn't matter if you group `p` elements that _don't_ fall under a `note` together with their preceding `other` element as long as you output the group without a wrapper.

Comment: Awesome. Stack guidelines advise against thanking ppl ("You're not here to socialize"), but thanks! Accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

You're group on either `<note>` or `<p>`. Hence the failing.

### Hint

You can try by using `group-starting-with="note"`,as describe in [Grouping With XSLT 2.0 @ XML.com](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1314):

```
<xsl:template match="doc">
  <doc>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="note">
      <notegroup>
      <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="self::note or self::p" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </notegroup>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </doc>
</xsl:template>
```

You may need another `<xsl:apply-templates />` around the end.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Eduardo - but is that xsl:apply-templates select="note|p" or *[self::note or self::p], the suggested code doesnt compile - both these edits produce bad results.